# What is causing this IllegalArgumentException: Service not Registered?

Tags: android, android-service

Whenever I either rotate the phone or press the Home button the application crashes and I get the following exception:

```
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.liteapps.handin_3/com.liteapps.handin_3.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.liteapps.handin_3.MainActivity$2@42116cf0
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3363)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3417)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3615)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:142)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1214)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.liteapps.handin_3.MainActivity$2@42116cf0
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:917)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1253)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:405)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at com.liteapps.handin_3.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:71)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1204)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5146)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3358)
11-25 22:17:23.855: E/AndroidRuntime(5033):     ... 12 more
```

And this is mConnection

```
  /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
{

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

I already registered my service - At least I think I did so by inserting the following in my manifest :

```
<service android:name="StationService" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised my problem was unbinding my service at times when the service wasn't bound in the first place. Only unbinding the service in onPause() seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that you are binding and unbinding from the same context. I was getting this error and discovered it was because I had previously implemented a context wrapper with which I was binding my service. My unbind was on the View context and so it had no knowledge of the service binding/registration.

Answer (score 0):

register your service in application manifest file.

Comment: The server is indeed registered in the manifest. (<service android:name="StationService" />)

Answer (score 0):

Your service is registered incorrectly in your manifest. It should either be:

`<service android:name=".StationService" />`

If the service is in the same Java package as the package specified in your manifest.

Or if the `Service` is in a different Java package to that registered in your manifest then you need to specify the full package name:

`<service android:name="com.example.package.StationService" />`

Comment: I figured that might be the problem. However nether having .StationService, Service or com.example.package.StationService has any effect whatsoever. Removing it alltogether however will make the application crash if I try to use the service.