# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered

Tags: android, android-webview, android-service

I have a app which contains webview. Every thing is going well but in my run tab in android studio. I am getting below message. My app still working fine. But it still bugging me. I don't know much about this message.

```
Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lx@643d3c7
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1526)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1717)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:722)
        at ci.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615046@20.36.15 (040306-0):1)
        at ci.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615046@20.36.15 (040306-0):6)
        at ly.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615046@20.36.15 (040306-0):10)
        at li.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615046@20.36.15 (040306-0):3)
        at ec.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615046@20.36.15 (040306-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at jb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615046@20.36.15 (040306-0):6)
```

I searched google and come to know I have to declare service in manifest file.

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600695/13485181

But I don't know which service I have to declare in manifest.

**UPDATE**

This Post is similar to mine

[Android foreground service consistently throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62217275/13485181)

The Accepted answer is good

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62220764/13485181

I also use

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

So I guess this dependency causing that message. But is there any way to remove that message although it's not effect the app.

**Dependency**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

Comment: class which you used that is the class which you extended to `Service` ..that class you need to declare in `manifest`

Comment: Sorry, But I don't think I have  intentionally used any Service. Or have any class that extends any service. Is there any way to know which service is being used in app.  I don't know about service concept.

Comment: Are you using Play Services libraries?

Comment: Yes @Wini I just update my question

Comment: can you add your dependencies here? what have you included in your dependencies?

Comment: @Wini  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

Comment: just post up all dependencies in question

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, you will have to redo your app based on the latest methods on launching the app
Google revamped pretty much the entire plumbing...

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/