# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@9577bef

Tags: flutter

I have read a similar post about Service not registered like this one
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059880/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-not-registered)
but it was in java.

console output:

```
W/ConnectionTracker(21680): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(21680): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@9577bef
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1757)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at lq.D(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):10)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at lc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(21680):     at ix.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):6)
```

my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  firebase_core: "0.5.2"
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

Comment: But it's the same error as the other question. I expect it's the same problem: I don't think it matters that you're using Flutter.